# Create dynamic grid (row and col) for data coming from API call

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am completely new to React JS and JavaScript. I am practising by making small project. I am not able make dynamic row and col. so that I can have 4 col of data and for 5th data, it should make new row and col and should continue until the end of data.

For example

[image]

Below is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './itemslist.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



class ItemsList extends Component{

  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    productList: []
  }
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const homeAPI = `${window.apiHost}/api/items/`;
    await axios.get(homeAPI).then(res => {
      this.setState({productList: res.data.result.product_data})
    })
  }

  render(){

//this where i am not able to make row and col.

    const products = this.state.productList.map((product, i)=>{
      return(

          <div className="card text-center card_style" key={i} style={{marginBottom: '120px'}}>
            <div className="card-header">
              {product.name}
            </div>
            <Link to={`/items/${product.id}`}>
              <img className="card-img-top card_image" src={product.image} alt="Card"/>
            </Link>
            <div className="card-footer text-muted">
              <p className="card-text">{product.description}</p>
              {product.price}
            </div>
          </div>

      )
    }
  )
    return(
      <div className="item_list_main">
        {products}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default ItemsList;
```

How can I proceed on this?

Comment: Can you add your css file. What have you tried till now to wrap your products?

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha i have tried with CSS but wasn't able to do it. i tried to wrap the products but i failed at that too.

Comment: You have to make use of flexbox or grid.

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha i am able to make that row and col with grid but to make it dynamically is what i am not able to do.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your css file.

For more refer 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```
.item_list_main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

This means that for one row your columns will be of four fragments.

Answer (score 0):

@Milan_Thapa. You can use width: 25%; in every component.
But let's say component size can be different. Width and height can be very different.

The best choice is to use Masonry which is very popular in this case.

https://masonry.desandro.com/

Hope this works.

Comment: i will try this.